# Intercept incoming SMS

Tags: c++, sms, symbian, carbide

I'm developing an app for Symbian device that need to silent filter incoming SMS, and the following link is the code that does that:

http://symbian.devtricks.mobi/tricks/silent_receiving_of_sms_messages/

another similar code on Nokia

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/SMS_Utilities_API

It work, but the problem is after I reboot my phone those SMS has been intercept will still add to inbox. I know on the site they did mention to use KIoctlReadMessageSucceeded to prevent that, which I did; but the problem still there. Tried both code but still same result. Is there anything I'm missing?

Another problem with that code is that it will no longer work after a call came in, sms won't be intercept anymore after that. Is that a way to fix that?

Thanks, help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We regards to not intercepting SMS after a reboot, are you re-starting your executable (and hence the listener) after a reboot?
You can do so with the Nokia [startup list management API](http://www.forum.nokia.com/document/Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-759FBC7F-5384-4487-8457-A8D4B76F6AA6/html/Startup_List_Management_API4.html).

With regards to failing after a call has come in, this sounds like your executable may be panicing (and thus stopping listening). Have you checked to see if it is panicing and whether it is still running after a call has come in?
I've done this kind of application before, and never had any problem with incoming calls.

Comment: It's still intercept SMS after reboot, the problem is the previous SMS that has been intercept are show as new message on inbox after reboot.

Regarding the panic after call came in, what kind of panic should I handle?

Comment: You can't 'handle' a panic - its a programming error. You need to determine whether your executable is indeed panicing, or meerely throwing an error - have you logged its behaviour or used on-target debugging to debug through?